# Excel - program cells to change colour based on another cell on another sheet

Tags: excel, formatting, formula, cell, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a formula for Excel whereby a cell would change color based on the number in the cell.

So for example, if cell H3 of sheet 1 is 50% of cell H3 on sheet 2, I would like H3 on sheet1 to turn green, if it´s higher turn yellow until 75% and then red.

next, if cell H4 of sheet 1 is 50% of cell H4 on sheet 2, I would like H4 on sheet1 to turn green, if it´s higher turn yellow until 75% and then red.

and this until all the other cell´s just at H50!!

thank you for your help

Comment: This is provided by Excel as 'Conditional Formatting'. On the 'Home' panel, select 'Conditional Formatting', 'Color Scales'.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without any programming. Simply using `Conditional Formatting` and thoughtfully ordering your rules will achieve this. This will take 3 separate rules in your logic

First, Highlight the cells you want to format and select `Conditional Formatting` in the Home tab of the ribbon.

Second, select `New Rule` and choose "Format only cells that contain" and choose "less than or equal to" (depending whether you want that, you said equal, I figured you wanted equal or less than). Then in the third box select the cell of the range in the second sheet making sure the cell reference is unlocked (no $'s) and multiply by .5

Third, same approach but now do the .75 condition, and the last one use .75 again but select "Equal to or greater than" depending how you want to treat exact .75 matches.

Lastly, when ordering the conditions, start with the lowest value threshold being the highest in the order.